# Low fps fireball animation

Tags: particles, baking

I tried to make a fireball animation in blender by adding a sphere->quick smoke->change settings in the domain.Then I added a cloud texture and baked the data.I can't solve the low fps problem.I already tried the simplify method, but it didn't work.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My fire animation moves very slow after baking data and I don't know how to make it move faster( low fps).

Comment: You have a high resolution smoke simulation and you are trying to render it at the same time (not to mention it brin a Cycles render with hundreds of samples to do). That's not going to happen at a high fps.

Comment: It moves much faster now.Thank you!